# Css divs layout issue

Tags: css

Please take a look at this laytout which i built with `divs`:

[image]

First of all you can ignore `Header` section

So `Content` has to be centered exactly at the center and it has a fixed width which is easy, but `Left Column` needs to extend from left side until it reaches `Content` and here is the difficult part, since the gap betwen `Left Column` and `Content` can be any length it's hard to know what `width` to set.

Now i know it would be fairly easy to do this with `javascript` but i would like to avoid that if possible.

**EDIT** as requested here is the code:

```
<div class="left_column"></div>
<div class="content"></div>

.left_column{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   float:left;
}

.content{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   margin:auto;
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: @pivot I have included my code

Comment: this is about as close as I could get it: http://jsfiddle.net/pivotconcepts/Bv9JG/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried percentages?

```
overflow: auto;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 45%;
```

try float left float right as well as display inline, you could also try width auto but that don't work too well

```
float:left;
 width:auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline;
```

there is also one more trick used in menus

```
    <div id="mail_menu">
     <ul>
     <li><a href=something</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#mail_menu {
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px; /* LTR */
 z-index: 3;
 color: #000;
}
#mail_menu ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
#mail_menu li {
 display: inline;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 3px;
}
#mail_menu a {
 color: #000;
 background: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 1px;
 border-color:#CCC;
 border-width:1px 0;
 padding: 2px;
 float:left;
 border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-bottom-color:#aaa;
  border-right-color:#aaa;
  border-top-color:#ddd;
  border-left-color:#ddd;
  border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;



}
#mail_menu a:hover {
 color: #0000DD;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-image: url(/images/lyel.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

css to middle something

```
.middle {
 display: block;
 width: 50em;

 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto
}
```

and finally some table values for display to mess with

```
.td {
display: table-cell;
display:inline
}

.wrap{
 position: inherit;
}

.tr {
display: table-row;
display:inline
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  text-align: left; /* LTR */
  padding-right: 1em; /* LTR */
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: for some reason if i use percentages, and both of the divs doesn't fit one div goes below, how can i fix that?

Comment: updated my post - ahh yes i seen that - the reason your being too precise about percentages so if u reduced one side to 30% other to 60% you may find it all shows up. But the problem is for screens smaller than yours.  http://myprofessions.com/tradefinder/FindATrader take a look at my site all the css's there feel free to help yourself, in the end I think I used table + css combo to make it work

Comment: lastly try position: absolute;

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  [Object-Oriented CSS](http://oocss.org/). In particular, check out [their grids page](http://oocss.org/grids_docs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use percentages, but go 1% short of where you should.  I've found a lot of times a browser will "round up" a pixel or something, so if you have your percentages totaling 100%, any extra added will push a div below.

For instance, if you wanted two divs, one on the right and one on the left, have one of them have `width:49%;` and the other `width:50%;`.

Comment: Please see my update, `content` has a fixed width, so your solution does not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using this hack, please try this:

```
div.header { height: 50px; line-height: 50px; background-color: #222; color: #eee; }
div.wrapper { background-color: #b261da;position: relative;z-index: 0; }
div.wrapper div.content { width: 600px;margin: 0 auto; background-color: #6189fe; color: #fefefe; }
div.wrapper div.left-column { background-color: #00fe72; position: relative;width: 550px;float: left;z-index: -1000; }
```

with this markup:

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-column">Left Column</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

**Note** the `left-column` will be cutted if you resize the screen too much. Either way, I hope it helps.